# How to use google Ajax crawling with Angular

Tags: angularjs

Google supports a scheme where you can indicate that a page has dynamic content, it requires the fragment url to start with a !, like dynamic.html#!part

Angularjs has very nice routing support but it seems to require that the fragment always starts with a /. Does anybody know a way to let these fragments start with a !?

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992

Answer (score 5):

I am just starting with Angular myself, but I think you want to set the `hashPrefix` of the `$location` service.

See the developer guide on the [$location service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location).

From the example it looks like you would do something along the lines of:

```
// Not 100% sure this is right
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

There also appears to be a more automated way of doing this, outlined in the section titled "Crawling your app" near the bottom of the same documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

If your running a ruby app - there's a gem that implements the crawling scheme for any rack app `gem install google_ajax_crawler` source code at  https://github.com/benkitzelman/google-ajax-crawler